# LESSPHP Links in Variables

Tags: less, lessphp

I need to use a less variable to import google fonts into a stylesheet.
The current way I am doing it is: `@import url(@{googleFonts});`
The variable I am passing into LESSPHP is: `"googleFonts" => "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Linden+Hill"`
However, all it is compiling to is: `import url(http);`

The past import statement I tried was: `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{googleFonts});`
With the variable of just: `Linden+Hall`

This worked better, but the problem I ran into here was the + was being stripped. Leaving just `LindenHall`.

So if you know how to make the compiler leave the + alone, then that works just fine aswell!

Answer (score 2):

Try an extra set of quote marks around your path (note the `'`):

```
"googleFonts" => "'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Linden+Hill'"
```

From the [LESS PHP documentation](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php), it states:

> Be aware that the value of the variable is a string containing a CSS
>   value. So if you want to pass a LESS string in, you're going to need
>   two sets of quotes. One for PHP and one for LESS.